# If "dar" means "to give", what does "daros" mean?

Tags: verbos, pronombres, objetos-indirectos, enclisis

In the sentence, "Queremos daros una pequeño parte para el viaje a España" (from Olly Richards' *Short Stories in Spanish for Beginners, Volume 1*) what is the "os" in "daros" for, if "dar" means "to give"?

Comment: Note: It should be _una **pequeña** parte_ – the adjective should match the noun it’s modifying.

Answer (score 12):

It's the second person plural *object* pronoun 'os' (as opposed to the *subject* pronoun 'vosotros'). It means 'you (plural)'. You would also use it where in English you might use 'to you' or 'for you' etc.

When such a pronoun occurs directly after an infinitive verb (or a gerund, or a positive command), it attaches to the end of the verb (this is called enclisis).

E.g.

> - Queremos daros - We want to give you (pl.)
> - Queremos darte - We want to give you (sing.)
> - Queremos darle - We want to give him

Comment: *darle* could also mean give you for the use of usted as second person pronoun

Answer (score 3):

*Daros* is used just in Spain, it means give you in plural.

In some countries of Latin America we use *darles*.

Comment: This is incomplete. The reason for "daros" vs "darles" is the usage of "vosotros" vs "ustedes", the usage is therefore dependent on the form of addressing and not the country of origin (although the addressing form IS primarily culture- and county-dependent)